# Croozer hitch -- axle quick release lever on the left?

Tags: trailer

The croozer manual states that to mount the axle hitch [with the hitch on the left/non-drive side and the quick release axle skewer oriented such that the quick release is on the right/drive side]:

> The quick-release lever must be positioned on the right side of the
>   bicycle (relative to the direction of travel). If the lever is on the
>   left side, the quick-release skewer must be removed and reinserted
>   from the right side

I'm not sure I want to put the QR on the cassette side though :/ . Does anyone know why they want the QR on the right here?

Comment: Here is the manual with some pictures: http://cms.croozer.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/CroozerKid-KidPlus16-ENG-F-NAAUS-9-16-WEB.pdf

Comment: The QR is usually mounted on the non-drive side because there's no risk of dirty fingers or wounds caused by the sprockets. But there's also no reason not to put it there especially if recommended for obvious reasons of interference as explained by the manufacturer of the Croozer.

Comment: I edited the question a bit because without pictures, it almost sounds like the axle hitch is supposed to be on the drive side. It isn't.

Comment: My hitch said the same, but I ignored the advice and left the QR on the left side where its not getting as dirty from chain debris.   But I also wrap the safety chain around in such a way it could never snag the QR.    Sounds like manufacturer liability avoidance at the cost of best-practice.

Answer (score 2):

This is about adding a hitch for a bike trailer. I can see why the company recommends to have the quick release on the right (cassette) side, whereas it is usually on the left. The hitch mechanism needs room and is often secured with an additional strap. By putting the quick release to the right, there is no danger of the hitch (and the strap) interacting with the quick release lever.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried mounting the hitch on the non-drive side, and the problem was that the hitch itself is slightly in the way of the quick release lever so I can't actually close the lever. I now mounted it on the right side as recommended by the manual.

Comment: The QR lever fowling with the hitch is one thing but he bigger issue is the one Christian raises which is that the safety strap could easily yank a QR lever open which would be a catastrophic failure mode.

Comment: Strangely though, Croozer also has this axle with an integrated hitch, and here, the lever and the hitch are on the same side :/ https://www.croozer.com/de-DE/cc-schnellspanner

Comment: I wonder if Croozer's is designed such that the lever can only point backward (towards the lever) such that there's. no possibility of the safety strap entangling.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Own work]
<sub>View from left hand side of bike, so trailer would be to the right of photo.</sub>

I have a 20" folder and it has an inordinate amount of grit and dirt and dust from the chain.  So putting the QR on the drive side would expose the cam to a lot more contamination.

For my trailer, I mount the towball on the left-hand-side and have the QR pointing forward.

The safety cable goes around the main spar and back to the trailer draw-bar.  There's no way the QR could be opened by any part of the trailer - its more likely to catch a stick or some vines or grass.

So you do whatever works for you on your bike.